# How to reference ID of DIV sending JavaScript call?

Tags: jquery

If I have:

```
<div id="selectbox" onclick="selectme();">
</div>
```

And if I call:

```
function selectme()
{
  var divselection=$(this);
}
```

I can't reference `$('#selectbox')`. What's the best way of referencing back to the div without having to passing it through as a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You have 3 possibilities:

1. Pass it as argument: `onclick="selectme(this);"`
2. Fetch it by id:

   ```
   function selectme() {
       var divselection = $('#selectbox');
   }
   ```
3. Not mix markup and javascript and attach the onclick handler unobtrusively:

   ```
   <div id="selectbox">
   </div>
   ```

   and then in a separate javascript file:

   ```
   $(function() {
       $('#selectbox').click(function() {
           var divselection = $(this);  
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Thanks, 1 was what I was looking for. Trying to call the function without passing the specific div ID

Answer (score 0):

If you attach event with jQuery you can use `$(this);`

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectbox").click(selectme);
});

function selectme() {
    // $(this) will give you div element
}
```

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dZ7zk/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (haven't tried it):

```
<div id="selectbox" onclick="selectme(this);">
</div>


function selectme(e){
 e.style.background='black';
}
```

But if not this will work for sure:

```
<div id="selectbox" onclick="selectme('selectbox');">
</div>


function selectme(e){
 document.getElementById(e).style.background='black';
}
```