# Javascript: error cannot set property '...' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Why is this line of JS code returning the error "cannot set property ... of undefined"?

```
document.forms["myForm"]["english_error"].textContent = "English sentence is required";
```

I am referencing the id of my div element correctly.

```
<input type="text" id="english" name="english" placeholder="English sentence" />
<div id="english_error" class="val_error"></div>
```

Comment: Assuming those elements are in `myForm`, not all elements with an ID will show up as properties of the `form` element. Mainly form controls will.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference ID of DIV sending JavaScript call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517003/how-to-reference-id-of-div-sending-javascript-call)

Answer (score 1):

Only form controls are mapped, basically only `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` tags:

```
var sentence = document.forms["myForm"]["english"];
```

Is an `<input>` tag so this works:

```
document.forms["myForm"]["english_error"].textContent = "English sentence is required";
```

`english_error` is normal `<div>` so doesn't work, you have to use:

```
document.getElementById("english_error").textContent = "English sentence is required";
```

And also by class name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("val_error")[0].textContent = "English sentence is required";
```